# Draggable listitem disappears when moving accross div

Tags: jquery

My question has been asked before on this forum and I have checked most of those threads but none of the solutions there worked in my case so that's why I'm starting a new thread.

I have two lists that I would like to combine in a third list. For this I would like to use the Draggable-functionality from jQuery for the two lists and also use the Sortable-functionality for the last list.

However when I move something from the first list, the item disappears behind the second div.

Suggestions like removing the `overflow:hidden` didn't work for me as I don't use any overflow. So that's why I would prefer some jQuery expert to have a look at it.

The fiddle can be found on http://jsfiddle.net/nku6Ln7r/

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove`position:relative` from messageLeft and messageRight.

See your updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nku6Ln7r/3/

Comment: That simple huh? ;-) Thank you Zealander!

Comment: yeah, when you specify `position`, `z-index` comes into play - where each positioned element occupies a stacking order slot . Which means one element will be "above" another.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`zIndex`](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-zIndex) option of draggable widget like:

```
$(".draggable").draggable({
    revert: true,
    helper: "clone",
    connectToSortable: "#stories",
    zIndex:999 // set this to a high value
});
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nku6Ln7r/1/)